# How to create and emoji in my project like Facebook?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to create a drop-down box of emoji like Facebook.
But I don't know where to start and how to implement emojis in my code.

Comment: Maybe you can use a search-engine, and search for "angular emoji".

Comment: I want to create this using core Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the best way, but here it goes.

Visit https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html and open the console.

To select all emojis, write the following in the console:

```
copy(Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("chars")).map(el => el.innerHTML));
```

This will give you an array of emojis in your clipboard. Use ctrl + v to paste them in your code.

How you want to embed them in your application is up to you. I'd create a container with a `<ul>` and map trough the emoji-array, creating an individual `<li>` for each one.

Comment: Thank you. Can I make Unicode dynamically to create emoji? Or is there any other way to create emoji? In case of live project is it a good way to implement emoji?